# How to slice NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, slice

I have a NSMutableArray and need objects [0:5] only. Is there a simple way to slice? Can I drop all objects after index? Can I copy a sub-array to another NSMutableArray?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was looking at NSMutableArray and didn't see these in the reference.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the instance method `- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range`.

For example:

```
NSArray* slicedArray = [wholeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
```

Comment: Note that NSMakeRange(0,5) doesn't mean 'slice positions 0 to 5', it means 'take a slice starting at 0 and incrementing by 5'. It makes no difference with 0:5, but if you do 1:5 the distinction becomes important.

Comment: Yep, so using an `NSMakeRange(1, 5)` would mean that `slicedArray` would contain objects from `wholeArray` at indexes 1 to 6.

Comment: To avoid `NSRangeException` for less than 5 elements you should use: `[wholeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MAX(wholeArray.count, 5))]`

Comment: @Szu I think you'll find that we need `MIN` instead of `MAX` to prevent a crash :)

Comment: @JamesBedford: actually `slicedArray` would contain objects from `wholeArray` at indexes 1 to 5, not 1 to 6.

Answer (score 15):

I see James Bedford already answered how to extract a range of indexes. To delete the objects in a range from an NSMutableArray, you can use `[wholeArray removeObjectsInRange:...]`. To delete all objects after a particular index, you can create an appropriate range as `NSMakeRange(index, wholeArray.count - index)`.

Comment: Concise, simple and helpful. Thanks for the answer